# The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found when deploying a project

Tags: sql-server, ssis, clr, dts

I am working on jobs currently and when I want to deploy my project I am receiving the following error. I tried to  check the DTSPath  but I wasn't able to find it under the following path "go to regedit->HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE->SOFTWARES and under Microsoft Sql Server in SSIS"

> The path for 'ISServerExec.exe' cannot be found. The operation will
>   now exit. A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of
>   user-defined routine or aggregate "deploy_project_internal": 
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The path for 'ISServerExec.exe'
>   cannot be found. The operation will now exit.
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:     at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionSmi.EventSink.DispatchMessages(Boolean
>   ignoreNonFatalMessages)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQuerySmi(Boolean
>   sendToPipe)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource
>   1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteToPipe(SmiContext pipeContext)
>   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlPipe.ExecuteAndSend(SqlCommand
>   command)    at
>
> Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerConnectionControl.RaiseError(SysMessageId
>   messageId, SysMessageSeverity severity, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.IntegrationServices.Server.ServerApi.DeployProjectInternal(SqlInt64
>   deployId, SqlInt64 versionId, SqlInt64 projectId, SqlString
>   projectName) . (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27108)

Comment: Mine is at `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\130\SSIS\Setup\DTSPath` for SQL Server 2016. Replace the `130` with the correct folder. Then make sure the `(Default)` value looks something like this: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\

Comment: When checking the regedit, I cannot find the path you are having.When I try to modify the Default value, I get the following error : "Error writing the value's new contents"

Comment: What version of SQL Server and SSIS do you have installed?

Comment: SQL Server 2016

Comment: What's the furthest down this registry path that you see on your box? `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Setup` If you can see the `\Setup` folder at the end of the path, what does the `Edition` or `EditionType` say?

Comment: @digital.aaron I have the following path : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\ClientSetup I cannot find the Edition nor the EditionType. There are two variable : Default (value not set) and Path having "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\" as a value .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problem immediately:
http://thesqlgirl.com/2017/10/25/ssis-error-the-path-for-isserverexec-exe-cannot-be-found/

When I re-ran the SQL Installer and selected the instance I was having trouble with, I found that SSIS (Integration Services) wasn't installed, just like the article above suggested.  Somehow, when I had removed a secondary instance of SQL that was running on same server, it affected other instances.

Not shocking for a Microsoft product.